Smoke simulation rendering very differently in viewport and final render (cycles)
I'm working on a render which makes use of a couple smoke simulations, which are rendered on their own view layer with most of the other view layers being used for indirect lighting or holdouts. In the viewport, it appears as intended, but when it's rendered, half the smoke appears to be missing, mostly from one of the two smoke simulations.

On the right is the viewport, and is how the final render SHOULD look. On the left is what happens when that particular view layer is rendered.
I've already checked several things to try and fix this. I've tried rendering without a transparent background, rendering everything as a single view layer, making sure it's not an additive transparency issue (there isn't an add shader between a transparent shader and something else, which someone told me could be an issue), increasing volume and transparency bounces, etc. I'm completely at a loss as to what could be wrong here.
The only other thing I could imagine is going wrong is something to do with light/shadow linking, as I noticed shadow linking for a specific object was working correctly in the viewport and not in the final render, but none of the main lights used to light the whole scene are included in that shadow linking collection.

Because it might be relevant, here's the shader for the smoke domains. I'm wondering if this might be an issue with the domains themselves, but I'm not sure. If anyone has any questions or things they need to see to help diagnose this problem, let me know.

Answering my own question, but I figured it out: motion blur being enabled was causing the issue!
